# Delete row dynamically in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, forms, dom

I'm doing a form (a simple WEB form, based on the scripts from Tom Negrino, JavaScript 8, and w3Schools) where the user press the Submit button and some of the fields from the form are displayed in one table under the form.

This is the result

[Form](http://postimg.org/image/7p8un983d/)

Now, I want to delete the row , but only the row that the user wants to delete clicking on the  corresponding row.

This is my JavaScript

```
window.onload = initForms;

function initForms() {
    for (var i=0; i< document.forms.length; i++) {
        document.forms[i].onsubmit = validForm;
    }
    document.getElementById("sunroof").onclick = doorSet;

    document.getElementById("estado").selectedIndex = 0;
    document.getElementById("estado").onchange = populateDays;

    /***********/
    //document.getElementsByTagName("form")[0].onsubmit = addNode;
    /***********/

    document.getElementById("env").onclick = function() {
        myFunction()
    };

}

function validForm() {
    var allGood = true;
    var allTags = document.getElementsByTagName("*");

    for (var i=0; i<allTags.length; i++) {
        if (!validTag(allTags[i])) {
            allGood = false;
        }
    }
    return allGood;

    function validTag(thisTag) {
        var outClass = "";
        var allClasses = thisTag.className.split(" ");

        for (var j=0; j<allClasses.length; j++) {
            outClass += validBasedOnClass(allClasses[j]) + " ";
        }

        thisTag.className = outClass;

        if (outClass.indexOf("invalid") > -1) {
            invalidLabel(thisTag.parentNode);
            thisTag.focus();
            if (thisTag.nodeName == "INPUT") {
                thisTag.select();
            }
            return false;
        }
        return true;

        function validBasedOnClass(thisClass) {
            var classBack = "";

            switch(thisClass) {
                case "":
                case "invalid":
                    break;
                case "reqd":
                    if (allGood && thisTag.value == "") {
                        classBack = "invalid ";
                    }
                    classBack += thisClass;
                    break;
                case "radio":
                    if (allGood && !radioPicked(thisTag.name)) {
                        classBack = "invalid ";
                    }
                    classBack += thisClass;
                    break;
                case "email":
                    if (allGood && !validEmail(thisTag.value)) classBack = "invalid ";
                    break;
                case "isNum":
                case "isZip":
                    classBack += thisClass;
                    break;
                default:
                    if (allGood && !crossCheck(thisTag,thisClass)) {
                        classBack = "invalid ";
                    }
                    classBack += thisClass;
            }
            return classBack;
        }

        function crossCheck(inTag,otherFieldID) {
            if (!document.getElementById(otherFieldID)) {
                return false;
            }
            return (inTag.value != "" || document.getElementById(otherFieldID).value != "");
        }

        function validEmail(email) {
            var re = /^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,3})+$/;

            return re.test(email);
        }

        function radioPicked(radioName) {
            var radioSet = "";

            for (var k=0; k<document.forms.length; k++) {
                if (!radioSet) {
                    radioSet = document.forms[k][radioName];
                }
            }
            if (!radioSet) {
                return false;
            }
            for (k=0; k<radioSet.length; k++) {
                if (radioSet[k].checked) {
                    return true;
                }
            }
            return false;
        }

        /****Veamos si esto funciona****/

        /*function checkboxPicked(checkboxName) {
            var checkboxSet = "";

            for (var k = 0; k < document.forms.length; k++) {
                if (!checkboxSet) {
                    checkboxSet = document.forms[k][checkboxName];
                }
            }
            if (!checkboxSet) {
                return false;
            }
            for ( k = 0; k < checkboxSet.length; k++) {
                if (checkboxSet[k].checked) {
                    return true;
                }
            }
            return false;
        }*/

        /*****************************************/

        function invalidLabel(parentTag) {
            if (parentTag.nodeName == "LABEL") {
                parentTag.className += " invalid";
            }
        }
    }
}

function populateDays() {
    var tamps = new Array("Ikon Hatch", "Fiesta", "Focus", "Mustang");
    var nvoleon = new Array("Aveo", "Spark");
    var slp = new Array("Gol", "CrossFox", "Clasico", "Jetta");

    var estado = document.getElementById("estado");
    var estadoStr = estado.options[estado.selectedIndex].value;

    if (estadoStr != "") {
        var valueEst = parseInt(estadoStr);
        document.getElementById("ciudad").options.length = 0;

        if (valueEst == 0) {
            for (var i = 0; i < tamps.length; i++) {
                document.getElementById("ciudad").options[i] = new Option(tamps[i]);
            }
        } else if (valueEst == 1) {
            for (var i = 0; i < nvoleon.length; i++) {
                document.getElementById("ciudad").options[i] = new Option(nvoleon[i]);
            }
        } else if (valueEst == 2) {
            for (var i = 0; i < slp.length; i++) {
                document.getElementById("ciudad").options[i] = new Option(slp[i]);
            }
        }
    } else {
        document.getElementById("ciudad").options.length = 0;
        document.getElementById("ciudad").options[0] = new Option("Model");
    }
}

function doorSet() {
    if (this.checked) {
        document.getElementById("twoDoor").checked = true;
    }
}

/*****************************/

/*function addNode() {
    var inText = document.getElementById("estado").value;
    var inText1 = document.getElementById("ciudad").value;

    var newText = document.createTextNode(inText);
    var newText1 = document.createTextNode(inText1);

    var newGraf = document.createElement("table");
    newGraf.appendChild(newText);
    newGraf.appendChild(newText1);

    var docBody = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];
    docBody.appendChild(newGraf);

    return false;
}*/

function myFunction() {
    var table = document.getElementById("myTable");

    var email= document.getElementById("emailAddr").value;
    var brand=document.getElementById("estado").value;
    var model=document.getElementById("ciudad").value;

    var row = table.insertRow(1);
    var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
    var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
    var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);
    cell1.innerHTML = email;
    cell2.innerHTML = model;
    cell3.innerHTML = brand;
}
```

And my HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Formulario</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/script06.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/normalize.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap-3.2.0-dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap-3.2.0-dist/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
        <!--No se te olvide el css-->
        <!--<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap-3.2.0-dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap-3.2.0-dist/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">-->
        <script src="js/script08.js"></script>
        <!--No se te olvide el js-->
    </head>

    <body>
        <header></header>
        <main>
            <article>
                <p>
                    <h1>Choose your car</h1>
                </p>
            </article>
            <form action="#">
                <p>
                    <label for="emailAddr">Email Address:
                        <input id="emailAddr" type="text" size="40" class="reqd email">
                    </label>
                </p>
                <p>
                    <label for="passwd1">Password:
                        <input type="password" id="passwd1" class="reqd">
                    </label>
                </p>
                <p>
                    <label for="passwd2">Repeat Pass:
                        <input type="password" id="passwd2" class="reqd passwd1">
                    </label>
                </p>
                <!--<p>
                <label for="color">Colors:
                <select id="color" class="reqd">
                <option value="" selected>Choose a color</option>
                <option value="Red">Red</option>
                <option value="Green">Green</option>
                <option value="Blue">Blue</option>
                </select> </label>
                </p>-->
                <p>
                    Options: <label for="sunroof">
                        <input type="checkbox" id="sunroof" value="Yes">
                        Sunroof (Two door only)</label>
                    <label for="pWindows">
                        <input type="checkbox" id="pWindows" value="Yes">
                        Power Windows</label>
                </p>
                <p>
                    Doors: <label for="DoorCt"><!--Doors:&nbsp;&nbsp;-->
                        <input type="radio" id="twoDoor" name="DoorCt" value="twoDoor" class="radio">
                        Two</label>
                        <label for="DoorCt">
                        <input type="radio" id="fourDoor" name="DoorCt" value="fourDoor" class="radio">
                        Four </label>
                </p>
                <p>
                    <label>Brand:</label>
                    <select id="estado" class="reqd">
                        <option value="">Brand</option>
                        <option value="0">Ford</option>
                        <option value="1">Chevrolet</option>
                        <option value="2">Volkswagen</option>
                    </select>
                    &nbsp;
                    <select id="ciudad" class="reqd">
                        <option>Model</option>
                    </select>
                </p>
                <p>
                    <input type="submit" value="Enviar" id="env">
                    &nbsp;
                    <input type="reset">
                </p>
            </form>

            <br />

            <!--Veamos si funciona-->
            <table id="myTable">
                <tr>
                    <td>Email</td>
                    <td>Model</td>
                    <td>ID Brand</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                </tr>
            </table>

        </main>
        <footer></footer>
    </body>
</html>
```

I tried adding and extra cell in the JavaScript:

`cell4.innerHTML = <button onclick="myDeleteFunction()">Del</button>;`

where calls the function

```
function myDeleteFunction() {
    document.getElementById("myTable").deleteRow();
}
```

to delete to row, but it didn't work.

I'll appreciate any help. Thanks.

Comment: Can you create a Fiddle?

Comment: Where is *cell4* defined? The [*deleteRow*](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-HTML/html.html#ID-13114938) method requires the index of the row to be deleted. Please don't use [*w3schools*](http://www.w3fools.com), use the [*W3C*](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-HTML/html.html#ID-13114938) for the related specification and [*MDN*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLTableElement.deleteRow) or [*MSDN*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms536408(v=vs.85).aspx) for implementation details and examples.

Comment: Here's a fiddle with your code in it: http://jsfiddle.net/3fquj0z5/ without adding the extra JS, and I fixed some of your input elements by adding `/`

Comment: @user145400—using `/` to "close" empty elements doesn't add (or fix) **anything** useful to the markup, it's treated as useless junk in an HTML document.

Comment: @ArCiGo—see [*W3C HTML5 table element: deleteRow*](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/tabular-data.html#dom-table-deleterow). The index can be `-1` (remove the last row) or 0 to `rows.length - 1`. Otherwise an exception should be thrown. W3Schools is an awful site, please visit one or more of those recommended previously.

Comment: @user145400 The fiddle doesn't work

Comment: @RobG Yup that's right. ArCiGo: don't look at me, it's your code :)

Comment: @user145400 ehehe. It works on my IDE

Answer (score 1):

```
var node = nodes[0];
if (univArray[z].ownership != "public") {
    node.parentNode.removeChild(node)
}
```

Comment: Always prefer to answer with some explanation instead of only code.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to delete a table row based on a click on the row, you can use something like:

```
<tr onclick="this.parentNode.removeChild(this)">
```

If you want to do that based on a button in the row, then:

```
<tr>
  <td><button onclick="deleteRow(this)">Delete this row</button>
```

Then the *deleteRow* function is:

```
function deleteRow(element) {
  var row = upTo(element, 'tr');
  if (row) row.parentNode.removeChild(row);
}
```

A helper function

```
// Return first ancestor of el with tagName
// or undefined if not found
function upTo(el, tagName) {
  tagName = tagName.toLowerCase();

  while (el && el.parentNode) {
    el = el.parentNode;
    if (el.tagName && el.tagName.toLowerCase() == tagName) {
      return el;
    }
  }

  // Many DOM methods return null if they don't
  // find the element they are searching for
  // It would be OK to omit the following and just
  // return undefined
  return null;
}
```

The *deleteRow* function can be put anywhere inside a row, and the row can be in any type of table section element (head, body or foot). All you need to do is to pass a reference to any element inside the row (button, checkbox, cell, whatever).

The trouble with the *table.deleteRow* method is that you have to know the row index in the element that you're calling the method on. Rows have a *rowIndex* property that is their index in the table they are in, so you have to go up to the table to use that (i.e. row.parentNode.parentNode), whereas using the [*removeChild*](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Core/core.html#ID-1734834066) method doesn't require you to work out where in the table the row is, or to even know whether the parent is a head, body or foot section.

#### Edit

To add the listener dynamically, you can slightly modify the function and add a class to the buttons that will delete rows, e.g.

```
<!-- Sample markup -->
<table>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="button" class="rowDeleter" value="Delete Row">
  <tr>
    <td><input type="button" class="rowDeleter" value="Delete Row">
  <tr>
    <td><input type="button" class="rowDeleter" value="Delete Row">
</table>
```

Adding a class means you can easily identify the elements to add the listener to.

```
<script>
window.onload = function() {

  // querySelectorAll and addEventListener require IE 8 or higher, use some other
  // method if support for older browsers is required
  var els = document.querySelectorAll('.rowDeleter');

  for (var i=0, iLen=els.length; i<iLen; i++) {
    els[i].addEventListener('click', deleteRow, false);
  }
}

// When attached using addEventListener, this in the function
// will be the element that called the listener    
function deleteRow() {
  var row = upTo(this, 'tr');
  if (row) row.parentNode.removeChild(row);
}

// Previously shown helper
function upTo(el, tagName) {
  tagName = tagName.toLowerCase();

  while (el && el.parentNode) {
    el = el.parentNode;
    if (el.tagName && el.tagName.toLowerCase() == tagName) {
      return el;
    }
  }
  return null;
}

</script>
```

Comment: I'm using an external .js. How can I put these on my code? I'm not very familiarized with the DOM (but I understand you some things).

Comment: Searching and asking, finally I solved my problem: [code](http://postimg.org/image/srod188y3/)... the [result](http://postimg.org/image/djyv4rs2d/) Thanks for all and sorry for the inconvenient